# Insert automatically 100 columns procedure foreign key error SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I made a procedure that add 100 columns in a table but I really can't handle the situation.
The procedure is:

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [add_100*Product] AS
DECLARE @i int, @s int,@start DATETIME, @end DATETIME
SET @start=GETDATE()
SET @i=0
SET @s=0
WHILE @i<100
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Product(description, id_storage,name) VALUES (CONCAT('Electronics',CONVERT(nvarchar,@i)),@s+1,
          CONCAT('Laptop',CONVERT(nvarchar,@i)))
SET @i = @i + 1
SET @s = @s +1
END

SET @end = GETDATE()
GO
EXEC [add_100*Product]
```

At the first, my Product Table had only 4 columns:

```
id_product Description id_storage valability    name  
 1          Food         1         2016-10-10   Orange
 2          Electronics  1         2016-12-08   Laptop
 3          Jewelry      2         2017-04-03   Ring
 4          Food         3         2016-07-05   Pizza
```

After the execution of the procedure I have:

```
1   Food    1   2016-10-10  Orange
2   Electronics 1   2016-12-08  Laptop 
3   Jewelry 2   2017-04-03  Ring
4   Food    3   2016-07-05  Pizza
505 Electronics0    1   NULL    Laptop0
506 Electronics1    2   NULL    Laptop1
507 Electronics2    3   NULL    Laptop2
508 Electronics3    4   NULL    Laptop3
```

I got some errors when I execute the procedure, it says that:

```
 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint    "FK_Product_Storage". The conflict occurred in database "OnlineShop", table "dbo.Storage", column 'id_storage'.
```

My table storage looks:

```
id_storage storage_name
 1         Kentucky
 2         Lord
 3         Renois 
 4         Kentucky
```

What is the problem and how can I make to insert automatically 100 Products in the Product table without appearing that error and complication with Storage Table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your INSERT statement, you set `id_storage` to `@s+1`:

```
INSERT INTO Product(description, id_storage,name) 
VALUES (CONCAT('Electronics',CONVERT(nvarchar,@i))
, @s+1,
...
```

According to the error, the problem comes from `id_storage` in `Storage`:

- In your Storage table, you have only 4 rows with `id_storage` from 1 to 4.
- In you loop, @s goes from 0 to 99.

When @id is not equal to 1, 2, 3 or 4 (values from Storage), this value is not validated by the foreign key between storage.id_storage and Product.id_storage. 
The row is not inserted and you see this error message.

According to your loop, you are seeing this error for @s=0 or @s between 5 and 99.

---

It is not related to your error but this query does not 'add 100 columns'. It simply insert 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your Storage table only has 4 rows with id_storage values between 1 and 4. You are looping through from 0 to 100 and trying to insert @s into the Product table's id_storage column (which has a foreign key onto Storage.id_storage). Neither 0 nor the numbers 5-100 exist in Storage. Hence the error.